# MongoDB queries - $condition by element in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following aggregation pipeline consisting of a single `$redact` step:
(which is supposed to return all products for which the recorded number of sales exceeds the stock)

```
$redact:
{
  $cond: [
    { $gt: ["$sales", "$productInfo.0.stock"] },
    "$$KEEP",
    "$$PRUNE"
  ]
}
```

(the syntax above is specific to Compass, so no issues here)

Where the entities look something like:

```
{
   _id: 123,
   sales: 60,
   price: 80,
   productInfo: [
      {
         stock: 100
      }
   ]
}
```

However, the query above does not seem to work. My presumption is that the issue is caused by the comparison with `$productInfo.0.stock`, as replacing it with another direct attribute of the entity (e.g. `price`) runs without any issues.

How should such a query (`$cond` by `$gt` where one of the values is from an array/list) be specified?

Comment: Can you share one example of document stored in collection and desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `productionInfo.0.stock` syntax is the Mongo Query Language (MQL), which can be used in a `$match` or a `find`.

That particular construct is not availabl when using aggregation syntax, such as `"$fieldName"`.  Instead, you need to use `$arrayElemAt`, but that unfortunately doesn't support accessing fields in the reference element.

To get what you want, you will need to add a field in a prior stage that retrieves the desired element from the array, reference that object in the $redact, and then project out the temporary field, such as:

```
{$addFields: {firstProduct: {$arrayElemAt: [ "$productInfo", 0 ]}}},
{$redact:{
  $cond: [
    { $gt: ["$sales", "$productInfo.0.stock"] },
    "$$KEEP",
    "$$PRUNE"
  ]
}},
{$project: {firstProduct: 0}}
```